# Adding Reference Local file always reverts back to ProgramFiles file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a Binary folder in my application. I put all my external dlls in this folder and reference them all from this folder. We us telerik controls, when I get the latest dlls from telerik they are in ProgramFiles(x86)/telerik...etc. I then add these new dlls to my Binary folder. So I remove the telerik reference and then add a reference that is to the file in my Binary folder. When I add this file it always shows my 'Path' as being the file in my ProjectFiles directory not my Binary folder.

No matter what I have tried it always seems to  revert back to the Program Files file - when I need it to have the path to my Binary folder.